# How to handle multiple lookups of an object in composite/tree rest api Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am working on data migration project from production to developer sandbox and able to copy data of independent objects as well as parent child relationships using [composite/tree rest api of salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/requests_composite_sobject_tree.htm). 
I am stuck with one scenario as of now explained below:

NAP_News_Filter__c is an object having two lookups: NAP_Page_Builder__c and NAP_News_Item__c.

So as part of my understanding, NAP_Page_Builder__c and NAP_News_Item__c will become two individual parents and NAP_News_Filter__c will become child of both.

I am not able to understand how to handle such scenarios of two different jsons of different parent objects and both jsons will have same child. Because when second json will be passed, it will create duplicate record but what I want is child record having both parent lookups.

Can anyone who have knowledge on such scenarios help me out.